# Google Analytics Users Count is 0 while Active User Count is 1

Tags: google-analytics

In my Google Analytics account, the **Users** count is 0 while **Active Users** count is 1.

Why is the active user is not being identified as **Unique User** in Google Analytics?

[image: Here is attachment]

I just checked after 21 hours of Account creation and still the **User** count is 0 while in graph it is one for yesterday data.
[Here is attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRnNn.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look carefully you will see that the Users are set to 'Last 7 days' (which does not include today) while the Active User count is real-time. You can tweak the time period settings, but Users will never keep up with Active Users anyway because GA is always a bit behind re everything that isn't real-time.

Comment: Today,I just checked for yesterday data but still in User Count is 0 while in Graph count is showing 1. Will that User be update in by GA later ?

Comment: Probably. GA experts all say 'leave it 24 hours', although in my experience it usually resolves long before that. Just let it run and don't get obsessive about these minor differences, or (as one who has been there) you will waste a lot of time and energy. GA will track your traffic in a pretty meaningful way over time, and that's presumably what you want. There will be times when it drives you up the wall. But it is free, after all!